# zum Schweigen gebracht werden

Tags: subjunctive, indirect-speech

I just read the following article: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/europa/nawalny-urteil-108.html

And I cannot figure out why Navalny would declare that he "solle zum Schweigen gebracht werden".

Could they possibly have meant to use a verb other than *sollen*? Why would he say that the Russian authorities should silence him?

On its own, "er solle zum Schweigen gebracht werden" tells me that supposedly, he's been silenced. But with the "Er hatte... erklärt, er solle zum Schweigen gebracht werden.", I'm at a loss as to why he'd urge his enemies to silence him.

Answer (score 5):

For context, here is the full sentence from the [article](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/europa/nawalny-urteil-108.html):

> Er hatte die Vorwürfe als frei erfunden zurückgewiesen und erklärt, er solle zum Schweigen gebracht werden.

And now, your concrete question:

> Why would he say that the Russian authorities should silence him?

You are right that "sollen" expresses someone's intention; someone's assumption that something is supposed to be in a certain way.

However (and this is indeed implicit here, it must be deduced from context), that person who has the described intention is not Nawalny himself. Thus, Nawalny does not explain what *he* thinks *should* happen, but what someone else, the powers that be, apparently think should happen to him.

It is to be understood as an unpersonal statement, describing an aspect of the world without making the subject of the action "sollen" explicit.

Answer (score 2):

*Solle* is Konjunktiv I, so this is hearsay or indirect speech.

> Er hatte ... erklärt, er solle zum Schweigen gebracht werden.

So what Nawalny does here is telling the audience that someone said:

> Er soll zum Schweigen gebracht werden.

This itself is a bit clumsy because if you were one of Putin's henchmen, you could also simply say:

> Er soll schweigen.

But that phrasing can't be put into indirect speech easily. Let me show you why:

> Er hatte ... erklärt, er solle schweigen.

See what happened here? Now it reads as if Nawalny was okay with that. That's the reason why they had put it with that construction *jemanden zum Schweigen bringen* which unmistakeably means *to silence someone.*